# Starting jquery fadeToggle hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I want to use fadeToggle to fade in and out some images automatically. It's working, but all the images start 'faded in', and I would like them to start invisible, so that they appear one by one. Thanks in advance!

```
    $(function () {
function run_animation($element, delay, duration) {
    $element.delay(delay).fadeToggle(duration, function () {
        run_animation($element, delay, duration);
    });
}
run_animation($('.pointer1'), 2000, 1000);
run_animation($('.pointer2'), 2500, 1000);
run_animation($('.pointer3'), 3000, 1000);
run_animation($('.pointer4'), 3500, 1000);
run_animation($('.pointer5'), 4000, 1000);
```

Comment: Can't you just make them invisible with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try by hiding images using CSS? Try `display:none` and if required you can call animation after `show()`.

Comment: Oh and one more question; is there a way to make them fade in and out in order? So that when image 1 fades out, nr. 2 fades in and so on?

Comment: you will have to use complete function http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/  refer to last example  `$("div").fadeIn(3000, function () {

    $("span").fadeIn(100);

  });`