# jQuery fadeToggle to be hidden from the beginning

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a responsive menu using the fadeToggle method in jQuery. When the width on the screen is less than 767px, a button is supposed to appear on the screen. When you press this button, a menu is supposed to show. But my problem is that the menu is visible from the start, even though I don't want it to be like that. I've tried to use the 'visibility:hidden;' property, but that didn't work.

If anyone has got a solution to my problem, I would be very thankful.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menuicon').click(function(){
    $('.menuclass').toggleClass('showMe');
    $('.menuclass').fadeToggle('.showMe');

}); 
});
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
img.menuicon {
    width:80px;
    visibility:visible;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;    
}

.menuclass {
    position:absolute;
    top:257px;
    z-index:10;
}

nav ul#meny li a {
    width:150px;
    padding:31px 0px 30px 0px;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;   
    font-size:1em;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    margin-left:-30px;
}

nav ul#meny li a.lastli {
    border-bottom-style:solid;
}

.showMe { 
    visibility:visible;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting jquery fadeToggle hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753361/starting-jquery-fadetoggle-hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you should use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden` in your CSS. jQuery applies `display: block` or `display: none` when you fade in and fade out.

Comment: I tried doing this but the result was the same as previously.

Comment: It seems to work now, I just had to adjust my jQuery code. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

All fade functions in jquery alter the display of an element. 
So you should use `display: none`. Something which always gives me great insight in the jQuery language is its docs: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/.